# Django no reverse match at /

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a picture the url to the post the picture represents, and I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

I am getting this error when trying to visit the home page of my site.

**Error during template rendering**

In template .../home.html, error at line 48

**Reverse for 'view_post' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P[0-9]+)/$']**

and the code it showcases

```
<a href="{% url 'view_post' post_id=post.post_id %}"><img src="media/{{ item.image }}"></a>
```

Also this is my view

```
def view_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id)
    return render(request,'gram/view_post.html',{'post': post})
```

And url

```
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.view_post, name='view_post'),
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the value of `post.post_id`? Try somewhere in the template `{{ post.post_id }}` and check the output.

Comment: As I can see your `post_id` values is empty string (from error line -
 `{'post_id': ''}`), but pattern match only with non-empty number `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some assumptions based on your code examples. This line:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id)
```

says that the class `Post` has a property `id`. However in your template you call `post.post_id`. Assuming that `post` is an object instance of the class `Post`, it should have the property `id`. Probably there is no such property like `post_id` in the class `Post`.

This means that in the template `post.post_id` won't return an output. Your urls, which are not shown here, expect an integer `['post/(?P[0-9]+)/$']`. Therefore the error is thrown.

Try this snippet:

```
{% url 'view_post' post_id=post.id %}
```

and check what happens.

As I said, this is based on some presumptions and I don't guarantee success.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. You were right about post_id not being a property of Post, checked {{ post.id }} in the template and it does have an integer value, but after changing  to {% url 'view_post' post_id=post.id %} I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @zmksa If the answer holds a solution for your problem, could you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I'm just stupid and made it hard for myself. The problem was I've done `<a href` in my home.html and home view didn't know what post.id is - obviously. The problem is fixed.

Comment: Is your problem completely fixed now?

Comment: Yes, once I added post.id to homepage everything works as planned and I can continue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If my answer didn't completely solve the issue and you came to the solution as described above, could you please expand your answer, so that it's helpful to other people too. You can then accept your own answer.